# Visual Studio 2008 SSIS BIDS XSD File Location After Build and Deploy ETL

Tags: ssis, xsd, etl, bids

Visual Studio 2008
SSIS/BIDS
Windows Server 2008/Windows 7 Enterprise

We're building BIDS packages and running them via [AutoSys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE). These BIDS packages have, as a component within a DataFlow, an **XML Source**. The XML Source points to an XML file and a corresponding XSD file that is generated (when you click, the Generate XSD... button) and saved out.

Right now, we're saving the XSD files to either a file server's temp directory. Basically, the data source XML files are at \server\share\data and the generated and saved out XSD files are at \server\share\data\temp.

The process running AutoSys has access to both the XML and XSD files.

Question: Are the XSD files required to be available when the .DTSX package is run? I can't seem to find an answer regarding this question.

Thanks!